# Jquery UI sortable issue: image invisible after drop on the dynamically created sortable (both uls have same parent div)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, drag, visible

I have the following problem:

I have got one sortable ul with one image (the green box). I want to be able to drag this image anywhere and create on this spot a new sortable ul(the grey box).

This part works perfectly.

Now I also want to be able to drag the image back from the gray box to the green one. It also works fine except one part: during the drag the image is invisible. How could I make the image visible during the drag?

I have checked: both uls seem to have same parent, I alert parentIds of both uls and it is the same . It is in both cases #images

How could I fix this problem?

I have created a jsfiddle for it: [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/Gy74c/)

```
$(document).ready (function() {   

                                  $( "ul" ).sortable({opacity:0.4, connectWith: 'ul', dropOnfull: true, stop: function (event,ui){
                                       var positionLeft=ui.position.left;
                                       var positionTop=ui.position.top;

                                       var x=$ ("<ul id='sortable10' class='drop'></ul>");
                                       $(x).css('position','absolute');
                                       $(x).css('left',positionLeft);
                                       $(x).css('top',positionTop); 
                                       $(x).css('height','70px');


                                       ui.item.appendTo(x);

                                       $(x).sortable({connectWith: 'ul'});
                                       $('#images').append(x);


                                       $( "ul" ).sortable({ connectWith: 'ul'});
                                         alert("ParentId of the gray box is "+$('ul#sortable10 ').parent().attr('id'));
                                         alert("ParentId of the green box is "+$('ul#sortable1 ').parent().attr('id'));
                                       } // stop-function
                                   });//sortable-options

                              })//main-function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guesses are that the ul is 'hiding' the element.. as you drag it around you can still see the image until the border of the ul..

I think you need to use divs or spans and make use of the draggable of jQuery ui..

Comment: I tried that right now. It worked even worse. Normally it is an issue that parents of uls are different, that is why I extra checked it.                                                                 Could it be a z-index issue? Because the image seems to be able to leave the gray box and is also properly attached to the green one, it is only invisible on the way.

Comment: Ok nice! I tried the z-index but that was not the problem. Good you solved it yourself! Sorry to put you in the wrong direction.

Comment: I am tahnkful that you at least tried to help me:) Maybe u could help me with that one, is my last issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638975/jquery-ui-sortable-propagation-dynamically-created-sortables

Comment: And your hint was the correct one at the end. It gave me another point of view to start the search with and at the end I have found the answer

Comment: haha i'm glad i could help just a little ;).. I'll see what i can do for ya there!